# Convert list of elements to mapped tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have an list of strings and a function that returns the proportion of equal text in each text.

example:

```
def proportion(text1, text2):
  ...

list_text = ['hey', 'hello', ..., 'bye'] (size n)
```

What I want is to calculate a tensor n by n with the result of the function N by N elements. Example:

```
result = [ 1/7 (hey, hey)   ...   3/4 (hey bye)]
         [ ...                                 ]
         [ 3/4 (hey bye)  ...     3/3 (bye bye)]
```

Is there any easy way?

Comment: add more explanation please.

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = len(list_text)
A = torch.empty(n,n)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        A[i,j] = proportion(list_text[i], list_text[j])
```